# Copy temporary buffer to out buffer

Tags: c++

In C++, how do I copy a temporary buffer (`buffer`) to out buffer (`outBuffer`) using `strncpy`?

```
void writeSensorStatus(SensorStatus& data, char* outBuffer[256])
{
  // create temporary buffer
  char buffer[256];
  const size_t capacity = JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(3);
  StaticJsonDocument<capacity> doc;

  
  serializeJson(data, buffer);
  strncpy(outBuffer, buffer, sizeof(outBuffer)); // Problem is here
}
```

I get the following error, on the lien trying to copy: `cannot convert 'char**' to 'char*'`

What I'm trying to do here is to retrieve the new values added to buffer outside the method. (Like a return)

Comment: `outBuffer` is an array of 256 `char*` values.  It is not a string.  Change the parameter to `char* outBuffer` and adjust the `strncpy` call appropriately (use `sizeof(buffer)`).

Comment: outBuffer appears to be an array of 256 pointers rather than an array of 256 chars.  Is that intentional?

Comment: No not intentional, it should be a char of 256 characters

Comment: Note that to rely on `sizeof(outBuffer)`, one option is to pass an array reference instead by defining your function parameter as `char (&outBuffer)[256]` -- this will force the caller to supply an actual array with the appropriate size.

Comment: Assuming the bug in the parameter is fixed, what is the point of using the temporary buffer? Why not simply call `serializeJson(data, outBuffer);`?

Comment: @eerorika I want to be able to have access to the `outBuffer` outside the method.

Comment: @Johnnyboy The temporary buffer seems entirely useless for that purpose.

Comment: @Johnnyboy *"I want to be able to have access to the `outBuffer` outside the method."* -- how does this desire prevent you from calling `serializeJson(data, outBuffer)` instead of `serializeJson(data, buffer)` (still assuming that the type of `outBuffer` is fixed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
void writeSensorStatus(SensorStatus& data, char* outBuffer[256])
```

When `char* outBuffer[256]` is passed as a function parameter, it decays to a pointer to a pointer to char, not a string.

Change this to:

```cpp
void writeSensorStatus(SensorStatus& data, char* outBuffer)
```

But this will affect `sizeof(outBuffer)`, so you can use what @paddy suggests, pass by reference:

```cpp
void writeSensorStatus(SensorStatus& data, char (&outBuffer)[256])
```

Comment: This addresses the error, but you should comment on how that affects the call to `strncpy`.

Comment: `char* outBuffer[256] is an array of 256 pointer` In any other context it would be. But `outBuffer` is a function parameter, and function parameters are never arrays. After adjustment, it is actually a pointer to the element of such array. In other words, `outBuffer` is a pointer to a pointer to char; it is not an array.